# google play console "Need login credentials for app review " error Although the credentials are correct

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk, google-play-console

I sent an app to review in google play console, and I got an email saying.

> Issue: Need login credentials for app review
> In order for us to review your app for compliance with Developer Program Policies, we will need you to provide valid login credentials for your app.
> If users need credentials to access your app, please provide all appropriate credentials via Play Console.
> If you previously supplied credentials, please ensure that they have not expired.
> If your app normally uses 2-Step Verification (e.g. SMS verification), biometrics (e.g. a fingerprint or face scan) or a location-dependent password (e.g. geo-gate), please provide valid demo credentials that we can use instead.
> We could not access in-app content due to app connection error

knowing that i already set a login credentials. the problem is that the credentials are working for me. i don't use a google sign in or something else to login. i use my api to login to the app.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a google support issue, not programming related